# Xcode 13.2.1 doesn't show IOS simulators

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am using Xcode 13.2.1 but under the component panel, there is no options to select the IOS simulators.

The screenshot shows the versions in my Xcode.
[image]

Comment: I'm gathering that by “components panel” you are referring to “Xcode” » “Preferences” » “Components”? I don’t see them in Xcode 13.2.1 either.

Comment: @Rob Yes, Under Xcode >> Preference >> Components, there is no IOS simulators that we can choose.

Comment: Yeah, but if you go to ”Window” » “Devices and Simulators” » “Simulators”, I assume you're seeing some there?

Comment: I suspect that the absence of them on the preferences components panel is a simple bug, but it really doesn't matter unless you need to download versions of simulators that you don't already have. To see what you've got installed, see the “Devices and Simulators” window.

Comment: @Rob I don't see the "Devices and Simulators" under "Window". LOL

Comment: What do you see under “Window” menu?

Comment: Regardless, the simulator list has reappeared in preferences in Xcode 13.2.1. Maybe there was some required endpoint in Apple's cloud that was temporarily down. It's back now.